Is it correct to put in brackets the professional title after the proper noun instead of putting the professional role before the proper noun?
“M'hemed Housseine Fantar (Archeologist) described”, or “the archaeologist M'Hemed Housseine Fantar described”?

How important is the fact that M'hemed Housseine Fantar is an archaeologist?

What context? Is this part of the text of an academic paper, newspaper story, caption, or something else? And is "Archaeologist" a professional title (something formally given by an employer, professional body, or educational institution) rather than just a description of their job or area of expertise?

Following up on Stuart F's comment, the capitalisation of the word in the first, but not the second, example is confusing: the word would be capitalised if it were some sort of a formally bestowed title (analogous to, say, Doctor), but not if it is merely a description (and which of the two it is may determine how it is to be handled).

You can use commas to set the profession off parenthetically.

M'hemed Housseine Fantar, an archeologist, described


This is surely a style choice. But for once I'll answer, because I've found some advice I like:

{5} Things to Avoid in Your Job Titles
...
2) Parentheses Mentioning something in parentheses in your job title
is usually a bad idea. It likely means that you feel that the text
before the parentheses wasn’t clear enough. Check out this Russel
Reynolds job advertisement:

Executive Search Researcher (Recruiting) ...

It would be better off using a title called “Researcher for
Recruiting” or “Recruiting Researcher”, or “Executive Recruiting
Researcher” if they wanted to go a bit on the long side.
...

[Rob Kelly; OnGig]
Though the example isn't exactly the same, the advice to avoid the clumsy format is still sound.
Of course, the formatting including brackets may be preferred in lists:

M'hemed Housseine Fantar (Archeologist)
Burt Reynolds (Researcher for Recruiting)
Rob Kelly (Professional Writer)
Grace Hopper (Computer Scientist and Rear Admiral)

but formatting in lists, tables, headlines and so on has different requirements from that in running text.
................
Note that the null article (not the identical-looking zero article) is available as well as the definite article:
Archaeologist Texas Jones described the find as 'epoch-defining'.
The archaeologist Texas Jones described the find as 'epoch-defining'.
